# rootViewController set but comes up as incorrect orientation

Tags: ios, nib, uiinterfaceorientation, uiapplicationdelegate

My situation is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532894/orientation-problem-when-i-set-a-rootviewcontroller) . I have an app that is universal where iPhone is in portrait orientation and the iPad is in Landscape and I switch between all of my main screens using the appDelegate.window.rootViewController = newScreen; The iPhone app works  perfectly. The iPad app will sometime throw the screen up in portrait orientation instead of landscape. Here is some sample transition code:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            ViewController* v = nil;
            if (IS_IPAD()) {
                v = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];
            }else{
                v = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
            }
            [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:(UIViewController*)v];
```

I also tried this from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053832/rootviewcontroller-animation-transition-initial-orientation-is-wrong) :

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            ViewController* v = nil;
            if (IS_IPAD()) {
                v = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];
            }else{
                v = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
            }

            [UIView
             transitionWithView:appDelegate.window 
             duration:0.5
             options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
             animations:^(void) {
                 BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
                 [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
                 [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:(UIViewController*)v];
                 [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
             } 
             completion:nil];
```

But nothing has fixed it.

Also tried using [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisable] and [appDelegate.window makeKeyWindow] in the hopes that this would "shock" it into doing the correct orientation.

Comment: This is a peculiar way to switch view controllers, which I've never seen before, but it may work. Did you add an appropriate `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to your view controllers? That should be the place where the interface orientation is determined.

Comment: I did indeed. Looks like this:  if (IS_IPAD()) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    }
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

Comment: Hmm. You could try to switch to a less rigorous way of switching VCs, e.g. by using a fixed (blank) view controller, and presenting your various views modally on them. This might keep the interface orientation fixed more reliably.

Comment: this is a full app that I'm just adding iPad on top of... if I can fix it in a less invasive way I would rather, but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks^^

Comment: Hey Matthew, did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it!

Here's what my transition block looks like. The key thing I did was copy the transform (the thing that does the actual rotation) from the CALayer. Note that you'll have to include the Quartz framework and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` at the top of your file.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window 
                  duration:0.5 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                animations:^{                        
    BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    target.view.layer.transform = window.rootViewController.view.layer.transform;
    window.rootViewController = target;
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Excellent fix, much appreciated!